# Angular-UI Bootstrap Modal requiring a timeout to close without error when closing from event

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm getting an error `current is null` when I am executing the following code in the controller of the modal.

```
 $scope.$on('cart:item_updated',function(evt, item){
      $modalInstance.close();
      //$timeout($modalInstance.close, 500);
 });
```

I had to add the timeout to get it to work. I believe it has to do with the digest cycle, but my concern is that the timeout fix is a hack that will not work depending on how quickly a user's device is able to process the code. I'd rather know what is going on here and solve this properly. If I execute the .close() via a user initiated action from a button within the modal it seems to perform the action as expected with no errors.

Comment: You will need to provide minimal reproduce scenario, ideally using http://plnkr.co/. Hard to help otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty limited to answer, however I am giving it a shot, you may try to use $scope.$watch instead of $scope.$on.